# Using foreach within a foreach with php

Tags: php, foreach

So I'm using a `foreach` to output my `table-cells` and have run into a problem with my output.

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

```html
<tr>
 <th scope="col"> <h3>Ember</h3>
  <p> Xeon E3-1231</p>
 </th>
 <th scope="col"> <h3>Ember</h3>
  <p> Xeon E3-1231</p>
 </th>
 <th scope="col"> <h3>Ember</h3>
  <p> Xeon E3-1231</p>
 </th>
 <th scope="col"> <h3>Ember</h3>
  <p> Xeon E3-1231</p>
 </th>
 <th scope="col"> <h3>Ember</h3>
  <p> Xeon E3-1231</p>
 </th>
</tr>
```

This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <?php 
    $tableheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_heading', 'type=text' );
    foreach ( $tableheading as $heading )
    { ?>
<th scope="col"> <h3><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>
<p>
<?php 
            $tablesub = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading' );
            if (!empty($tablesub)){

            $tablesubheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading', 'type=text' );
            foreach ( $tablesubheading as $subheading )
            { echo $subheading; } 

        } ?>
        </p>
    </th>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Which is giving me this:

```html
<tr>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember2</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember3</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember4</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember5</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>
  <th scope="col">
    <h3>Ember6</h3>
    <p>
      Xeon E3-1231v3Xeon E3-1231v3 2Xeon E3-1231v3 3Xeon E3-1231v3 4Xeon E3-1231v3 5Xeon E3-1231v3 6</p>
  </th>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of this, if your array keys are the same:

```
foreach( $tableheading as $index => $heading ) {
   echo $tablesubheading[$index];
}
```

It would be easier if you could integrate the $tablesubheading table into the $tableheading, though. Of course, I'm not sure if their keys are the same!

If they are, then in your example this would be:

```
<tr>
    <?php 
        $tableheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_heading', 'type=text' );
        foreach ( $tableheading as $index => $heading ) { 
    ?>
    <th scope="col"> <h3><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>
    <p>
        <?php 
                $tablesub = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading' );
                if (!empty($tablesub)) {
                    $tablesubheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading', 'type=text' );
                    echo $tablesubheading[$index];
                } 
                ?>
            </p>
        </th>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect!

Comment: The second example is echoing the sub-headings in this order: 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Could you update your question with a var_dump of both arrays? Then we can see if and why the keys are not matching

Comment: Sorry, you had it bang on... been looking at this for too long. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<p>` inside the inner loop:

```
foreach(...) {
   foreach(... as $foo) {
       echo "<p>$foo</p>";
   }
}
```

Since they're OUTSIDE the inner loop, you only get one `<p>` set, instead of one per inner-item.

Comment: The `<p>` isn't the problem it's the sub heading thats repeating the "Xeon E3-1231" text should be inserted into each table head.

Comment: then why run a foreach if you only want one header to be output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid the second foreach like so:

```
$tablesubheading = rwmb_meta( 'tb_table1_sub_heading', 'type=text' );
echo $tablesubheading[0];
```

Although I may have interpreted this completely wrong.